# Postman API to connect to Firebase Realtime DB

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database, postman

I am confused as to how to connect to my Firebase DB using, say Postman to send the REST requests.

In the screenshot below, you can see my DB structure and GET request.

Specifically, the GET request in Postman looks like this,
https://fir-crud-api-b1cec.firebaseio.com/products/test.json?auth=xxxx

while the DB is structured as such

> products > test.json

Would appreciate any advice to point me in the right direction. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your URL suggests that you want to use the Realtime Datbase REST API, but your screenshot suggests that your data is in Firestore.  These are different databases with different APIs.

If you want to work with data in Firestore, you should use the Fi[restore REST API instead](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api).

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot on the left shows the Cloud Firestore database, while in PostMan you are trying to access the Realtime Database. While both databases are part of Firebase, they're completely separate, and have completely separate REST APIs.

If you want to access Cloud Firestore from PostMan, have a look at its [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest). Fair warning that this API is significantly more complex than the one for the Realtime Database.

If you want to continue using the Realtime Database REST API, make sure to create your data structure in the [Realtime Database in the Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/firevotes/database/_/data).